# Невалидный инпут при копировании в него значенния

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4

Для инпута в реактивной форме стоит простейший валидатор для проверки телефона ( на скрине).
Если вводить номер вручную - все ок. Проблема: если копировать в инпут номер целиком, срабатывает валидатор т.к. инпут становится невалидным.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если удалить один символ и затем снова добавить или повторно скопировать весь номер в инпут - все возращается в валидное состояние

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вставьте сюда свой паттерн для меня плиз

Comment: /^\+380\d{9}$/g

Comment: какие у вас еще валидаторы висят на этом контроле? один или массив?

Comment: Один
'businessPhone': new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(REGEX.phone)]),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это известная проблема, которая больше похожа на побочный эффект, потому что он появляется при разных нюансах. Самые быстрое решение - это повесить обработчик события `paste` на ваш инпут и вызвать метод `updateValueAndValidity`, который пересчитывает значение и статус проверки контрола.

Шаблон:

```
<input formControlName="businessPhone" (paste)="pastePhone()">
```

Компонент:

```
public pastePhone(): void {
  this.название_вашей_формы.get('businessPhone').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: Суппер! Спасибо Вам!!)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а в чем заключается побочный эффект? Все равно не корректно срабатывает. Особенно при нескольких контроллах(

Comment: интересно, сделаете мини демо на стекблитц?

Comment: Я вчера сделал, но там все корректно работает даже без updateValueAndValidity
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vxysdz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Также если добавлять валидные значения телефонов методом patchValue(), то второй контрол всегда невалидным оказывается, до тех пор пока не удалить один символ и вернуть его. То-же поведение если в new FormControl добавлять начальное значение - второй контрол не валиден оказывается

Comment: у вас это во всех браузерах или в каком-то определенном? у меня например в хроме без updateValueAndValidity никогда не работает

Comment: Я пробовал в хроме и мозиле